# Accessing Reverse proxy in service fabric local cluster

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I am using service fabric sdk 2.5 with VS 2015. I have seen the article [How to configure and enable Azure Service Fabric Reverse Proxy for an existing on-premises cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881031/how-to-configure-and-enable-azure-service-fabric-reverse-proxy-for-an-existing-o) and tried to access my service via reverse proxy. But I am getting a message "Unable to connect". I have the below settings in FabricHostSettings.xml

```
<Parameter Name="HttpApplicationGatewayListenAddress" Value="19081" />
<Parameter Name="HttpApplicationGatewayProtocol" Value="http" />
```

Can anyone help to test reverse proxy setup in local dev cluster

Comment: Reverse proxy is enabled on local clusters but the port configuration can be tricky. I was able to do it after some investigation, and it's posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012427/service-fabric-reverse-proxy-port-configurability

If you're still getting 404's then your issue might lie with the communication listener on your service. Check that the endpoint is setup correctly in the service manifest and that your communication listener is respecting the assigned ports and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse proxy appears enabled by default now for local dev cluster. Check `clusterManifest.xml` and `FabricHostSettings.xml` in `C:\SfDevCluster\Data` for configured ports. Default is `19081`.